# Thumbnail Size in WordPress Shown in HomPage is Different

Tags: wordpress

The thumbnail size in the Dashboard > Settings > Media is set to 150x150 pixels. But the thumbnail shown in the homepage is of 128x128px. 
I actually want to reduce the size of thumbnail at homepage to 100x100px. I have tried editing the Media setting but no gain.
this is the theme im working on http://taimoorsultan.net76.net/
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

after editing  Dashboard > Settings > Media, you need to re-upload your images...

or easier/better is to use this plugin after setting that value...

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/